# Change focus to another window, where name is undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I'm using [WD.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) webdriver client for node.js to test my app.

In my app after a button click a new browser window opens.
Obviously by the nature of selenium the old window stays active.

I've tried to use the `window()` method from wd.js to switch to the new window but [it needs a window name as a parameter](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#POST_/session/%3asessionId/window) which isn't set.

Is there any way to switch between windows without knowing their name?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the version of webdriver you're using but the typical flow used to do something like this is:
1 - get window names, store only name; 
2 - do action that opens new window; 
3 - get window names; 
4 - switch to window that has different name to the first;    Can WD.js do that?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well, I cannot give the window a name because im not using a window.open() ... id like to be able to switch to the new window using something like 'driver.switchTo().window();'   and the below answer is for java, not javascript

Answer (score 2):

foo, i found the answer to this.

you will want to use this function here

```
var handlePromise = driver.getAllWindowHandles();
handlePromise.then(function (handles){
  var popUpWindow = handles[1];

  driver.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
})
```

1. here we are telling the driver to get all window handles
2. we then are passing the handles as a parameter to our function
3. we then are assigning the value of handles[1] (which is the new window) to the variable 'popUpWindow'
4. telling driver to switch to that new window

Comment: foo, i have tested this answer and it works, if it works for you accept

Comment: `browser.driver.switchTo.window is not a function`

Comment: sorry @chrismillah just read your answer... unfortunately we had to drop WebDriver after a short try so I'm unable to test your answer but it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked for all browsers:-
Try this code:-

```
var tab_handles =await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
let number_of_tabs = tab_handles.length;
let new_tab_index = number_of_tabs-1;
await driver.switchTo().window(tab_handles[new_tab_index]);
```

That was using await instead of Promise for async functions.

If you want to use Promise then try this code:-

```
driver.getAllWindowHandles().then((tab_handles)=>{
let number_of_tabs = tab_handles.length;
let new_tab_index = number_of_tabs-1;
driver.switchTo().window(tab_handles[new_tab_index]);
});
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following in java implementation ,

```
  String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
  WebDriver popup = null;
  Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
  while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
    String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
    popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    if (popup.getTitle().equals("Google") {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Here, the name is not mandatory. Similarly, can you try to loop over and switch ?
For your information,

```
 switchToWindow(name/Handle)
```

- Switch focus to a different browser window by name or handle. So try this and let the community know the solution. Good luck !

Comment: Yes, but he's using JavaScript

Comment: @LeeGee agreed. As I have mentioned I just gave him a suggestion on the approach and left the implementation for him. May be I  should try a POC on WD.js and come back.

Comment: I'm sure it would be appreciated. Note his window has no title. Assuming foo only has the two windows open, it ought to be simple.